# Confusing Probability Question.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

So A friend gave me a probability question to do but I can't seem to put my head around it.

I walk into a bar to see LA Lakers (Los Angeles Lakers) play basketball on TV. I order a drink and sit next to a man who is wearing a LA Lakers top and baseball cap and it seemed pretty obvious he was an LA Lakers fan. What is the probability that this man was actually from and lives in Los Angeles USA?

We can assume that 
. Probability of a random selected person chosen from a local bar and is a from and living in Los Angeles USA is 0.1
. Probability of a person from and living in Los Angeles USA actually supporting the LA Lakers is 0.6
. Probability of a person NOT from and NOT living in Los Angeles USA supports LA Lakers is 0.15

... I'm thinking it's something to do with bayes formula but i'm quite confused on how to do this.

Comment: I do not like how this question is phrased. The event "this particular man is from and lives in LA" is not random and assigning it a probability is as meaningless as answering "What is 1+1? (a) 1, (b) 2, (c) 3, (d) 4" by "Each, with probability $1/4$

Comment: He might consider cheering for the Clippers this year instead!

Answer (score 1):

$P(\text{the man is from and living in LA, given that he supports the Lakers})$

$=\frac{P(\text{the man is from and living in LA AND he supports the Lakers})}{P(\text{he supports the Lakers})}$

$=\frac{.6}{.6+.15}$

$=.8$

Comment: So I guess the $0.1$ doesn't figure at all into the answer?

Comment: @Doc: I don't think so. The question was about a specific man. Not a person in general

Comment: The way the problem is worded, I agree with you.  Good job. +1

Answer (score 0):

The probability of the lakers fan not being from Los Angelos USA is 0.15. So the probability of him being from Los Angelos USA is the opposite.

1-0.15

Since you know he's a fan the person at the bar is not randomly selected at the bar and the chance of him being a fan is 1.